# Grouping and Ordering ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that displays a list of application errors. As it stands everything is working and it displays the errors with the newest date first. I want to be able to Group the errors by which Application they are coming from and then order them by date. Here is what I currently have but I can't work out what I would need to add in order to group them by application. Can anyone please help?

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, int? page)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "TimeUtc" ? "timeutc_desc" : "TimeUtc";

    var applications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
                 select s;

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        default:
            applications = applications.OrderByDescending(s => s.TimeUtc);
                break;
    }
    int pageSize = Int32.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultPageSize"]);
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return View(applications.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this, but the simplest would be to order by application, then by date:

```
applications = applications.OrderBy(x=>x.Application).ThenByDescending(s => s.TimeUtc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method:-

```
var applications = db.ElmahErrors.GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationName)
                                 .Select(x => new 
                                       {
                                          ApplicationName = x.Key,
                                          Errors = x.OrderByDescending(s => s.TimeUtc);
                                       });
```

Here, I have considered that Application Name is stored in `ApplicationName` property.

Comment: I have tried this code and it gives me this error 'The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.'

Comment: @Megatron - That's because in my code, I am generating an anonymous type. As per your accepted answer you don't need group rather you simply need ordering.